# Why data and tag block in a cache are separated?

Tags: caching

let's consider a cache (for example a direct-mapped)...I see in some books that the block that contains the data is separated from the block that contains the tag, the validation bit, etc. 

So, I have two questions:
1 - They are phisically separated? 
2 - Why?

PS: Maybe an image could be useful to understand the problem: block tag and block data are those on the left and on the right of the red line, respectively

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The memory address (which contains the required byte) needs to be searched in cache **as fast as possible**. Therefore the `tag` area is a [Associative Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_memory) in which all the possible `tags` which represent the blocks/rows of cache can be searched simultaneously. One of the blocks/rows will contain the required byte. Once the block is found then, using the `offset` value/part of memory address the byte can be accessed. So there is difference in the way both, `data` and `tag` are accessed and hence the separation.

Comment: I didn't understand exactly..
1 - Tag area and data area are implemented using different caches, the first associative because offers better performance in terms of access time?
2 - The two areas are accessed simultaneously in parallel?
3 - What is the difference in accessing the two areas?
Thanks